# Common names for source and destination directories in compiled code

Tags: language-agnostic, convention, compiled

In compiled languages, there are two important folders:

1. The folder where you put your source code
2. The folder where your compiled code ends up

I've seen these folders called `source` and `build` quite a lot.

When building new systems and languages, one is in a position to choose the default names for these folders--and it is good to follow precedent.

What are the most common names for "source" and "destination" folders in projects built with compiled languages? Does anyone have any hard numbers?

Comment: Just to mention some: src/bin